# iOS 15.2 UILabel line break mode incorrect work

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, ios15.2

Faced the problem that on iOS 15.2 all labels incorrectly handle line break mode.
Below are examples of rendering labels:

**Line Break Mode:** *.byClipping*

- Xcode 13.0 iOS 15.0.

[image]

- Xcode 13.2.1 iOS 15.2

[image]

As you can see, the last word is truncated and does not remain on the line.

**Line Break Mode:** *.byTruncatingMiddle*

- Xcode 13.0 iOS 15.0.

[image]

- Xcode 13.2.1 iOS 15.2

[image]

Same issue on AppStore UILabels.
It seems that the bug is in the iOS SDK version. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Perhaps there are workarounds?

Comment: If you have found an iOS bug, file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I have filed the bug for you, but you should file it as well. The more reports, the better.

Comment: We ran into this as well and looks like they may have fixed it in Xcode 13.3.1 running iOS 15.4.